# GWT: how to fire custom events from View and consumed by Activity

Tags: gwt, event-handling, mvp, uibinder

I can't make a custom event be received in the Activity. Can anyone please tell me what am I missing? I am using GWT 2.1, MVP pattern and UiBinder.

Here's a sample of what I wrote:

Let's say I have `MyCustomEvent` class and its handler interface `MyCustomEventHandler` with its `onMyCustomEvent(MyCustomEvent event)` method.

I implement the handler interface in the Activity:

```
    class MyActivity extends AbstractActivity implements MyCustomEventHandler {
    ....

      public void onMyCustomEvent(MyCustomEvent event) {
        doWhatYouKnow();

      }

      //EventBus is injected with GIN
       public void start(AcceptsOneWidget container, EventBus eventBus) {


        ...         
        eventBus.addHandler(MyEvent.TYPE, this);


    }    



}
```

Now, the sending part in the view:

```
    public class MyWidget extends Composite {

    final PopUpPanel myPopUp;

        public MyWidget() {
             initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

             myPopUp.addCloseHandler(new CloseHandler<PopupPanel>() {

            @Override
            public void onClose(CloseEvent<PopupPanel> event) {

                       MyEvent event = new MyEvent();
               fireEvent(event);

            }

        });

         }

}
```

No exception are thrown and unfortunately `onMyCustomEvent` is never called in the `MyActivity` class. Any idea? Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

@MyWidget

you can make the constructor take parameter ( eventBus ) 
which you can pass this from class MyActivity

so when you fire the event @MyActivity
the action will be executed @MyWidget

try this , i think it will work .

Comment: Thank, your approach is also explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946242/passing-an-object-to-the-constructor-of-a-widget-defined-in-uibinder). But As far as my understanding, I don't understand why my approach doesn't work.

Comment: I did some more debug. The outcome of which appears weird to me. The eventBus implementation passed in start() method is not the same that is injected. Infact i inject a SimpleEventBus but in start() method a ResettableEventBus is used instead. I moved the eventBus.addHandler(MyEvent.TYPE, this); to the Activity constructor, which takes the eventBus as parameter. This assure the eventBus object is the same that ships with onModuleLoad(). Nevertheless, the receiver still remain untriggered though! I really can't get this done.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of your comments is pointing you in the right direction here.  What I'm going to guess is going on is that you have more than one `EventBus` floating around (there should usually only be one event bus per application).

First of all, make sure the `EventBus` in your Gin module is bound in the `Singleton` scope.  Also, make sure this is the event bus that you pass in to your `PlaceController`, and not one you're constructing on your own.

Also, I wouldn't be too worried about the fact that your object is a `ResettableEventBus` in one place.  I believe that's just an object that's created by the Activities/Places framework that just wraps the `EventBus` object you give it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually everything is in place as you described. I Found a workaround to solve my problem, leaving out the custom event creation approach: I found out that I could exploit a built in event from the widget reaching out the same solution. I also admit that I am a GWT newbie, may be I am missing some other part around.